# @font-face not working in Firefox, but works in Chrome

Tags: css

The fonts used to work, today they stopped working w/o any CSS changes. I can see from firebug net panel that the .woff gets downloaded (oddly twice, first DL is just a circle rolling forever and doesn't complete). Tested on FF9/10. Here's my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

a.css3button, button, input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"] {
    ..
    font-family: "bebasNeueRegular", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    ..
}
```

I got it from: http://dev.florianweber.me/bf3buttons/# -- where it does work in my Firefox. What could be causing conflicts?

Comment: Please trim your code to only include what is absolutely essential to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I showed it all, due if I knew what the cause is, I could have probably fixed it myself already.

Comment: Try generating on Font Squirrel - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had our CDN domain serving the .css file -- which I guess Firefox disliked. I set the hard path to the font files in to the .css and it seems to be working now. :)

```
font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
src: url('http://site.com/sites/default/themes/theme/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
src: url('http://site.com/sites/default/themes/theme/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://site.com/sites/default/themes/theme/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://site.com/sites/default/themes/theme/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://site.com/sites/default/themes/theme/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Another way:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
```

and

```
font-family: "bebasNeueRegular"
```

is not the same. Watch out for typos, font-family can be case sensitive.

Comment: Good catch, unfortunately this was not the issue, fixed typos still :)

Answer (score -2):

I figured out that Firefox loads the font names diffrent.

This did the trick for me, give it a try, don't know wich one is the good one, but it works. Try without brackets etc.

```
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular', Bebas Neue, 'Bebas Neue', bebas_neueregular;
```

Comment: Well, it's another way to solve this problem if the above answers ain't working.